# jQuery's selector is undefined when using webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I was learning webpack and had created a module to do a simple task: click an element to add this css property on it `margin-right: 5rem;`

```
import $ from 'jquery'

class ShiftRight {
    constructor() {
        this.more = $('.more')
        this.shifting()
    }

    shifting() {
        this.more.click(function() {
            this.more.addClass('more--clicked')
        })
    }
}

export default ShiftRight
```

HTML's part is simple too:

```
    <div class="more">
        <div class="more-sign"></div>
    </div>
```

The error message: `Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined`. How come `this.more` is undefined? Is that because of jQuery? What's the pure JavaScript way to cooperate with webpack in this case?

Comment: i have no idea what webpack is but I'll give it a shot, try this.addClass('more--clicked'); since you are in the handler of the button anyways.

Comment: Still the same error message...

Comment: Do what ProgrammerV5 said or use an arrow function to preserve the context `this.more.click(() => {
            this.more.addClass('more--clicked');
        });`

Comment: Usually arrow function doesn't work with `this` but anyway I gave it a shot too. Same error message.

Comment: The arrow function actually works. It didn't because `margin-right` not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery seems to be loaded because you get an error on `this.mode.addClass` not on `$(".mode")` or `this.more.click`.

The problem is the context, inside the click callback function, `this` doesn't refer to the `ShiftRight` instance, it refers to the clicked element. Using `$(this).addClass("more--clicked")`

```
shifting() {
    this.more.click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('more--clicked')
    })
}
```

or an arrow function

```
shifting() {
    this.more.click(() => {
        this.more.addClass('more--clicked')
    })
}
```

should fix that

Answer (score 0):

if it is a jquery problem try to add this to your webpack config

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
]
```